# How to print the object like string in console.log in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to print in the console the result from the function `printNewObject()`.  How I can print with console.log in Javascript the result from the object? In the output I get the result `Set {"1", "3", "4"}`, but I want to look like a string, like `134`.

**Here is the code:**

```
window.onload = function(){

  inputBox = document.getElementById("myText");
  btn = document.getElementById('sub');

  inputBox2 = document.getElementById("myText2");
  btn2 = document.getElementById('sub2');

  btn.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    toObject(inputBox.value);
  });

  btn2.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    printNewObject(inputBox.value, inputBox2.value);
  });

  function toObject(arr) {

    var rv = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
      rv[i] = arr[i];

    return rv;
  }

  function printNewObject(rv, number) {

    var mySet = new Set(rv);

    for (var i = 0; i <= rv.length; i++) {

      if (rv[i] == number) {
        mySet.delete(rv[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log(mySet);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function printNewObject(rv, number) {

    var mySet = new Set(rv);
    var st = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= rv.length; i++) {

        if (rv[i] == number) {
             mySet.delete(rv[i]);
        }
    }
    var array = Array.from(mySet);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        st += array[i];
    }
    console.log(st);
}
```